# Camera cuts on live Dragon capsule recovery as astronauts put on stretcher

Tags: dragon-v2, recovery

I noticed that, during the recovery of the astronauts of the first Dragon landing, the live streaming camera was placed beautifully on the ship and one viewpoint was used the entire time, *except* for a few seconds just as each astronaut is lifted onto the stretcher.  For those seconds, they cut away to a poor camera view.

Do we know why this was done?  Is this standard procedure for recovering astronauts or was it unusual?  HIPPA regulations perhaps?

Comment: If I remember the framing correctly, the astronauts themselves would have been blocked by the personnel helping them onto the stretcher, and you wouldn't have been able to, e.g. see the "thumbs up". But I might be misremembering. Note that for the past 10 years, astronauts have only landed in the middle of nowhere in Kazakhstan, so this would be the first time we have seen footage like this, and thus it is hard to tell what the standard procedure would be. It is also the first time *ever* that a company with commercial interests has recovered astronauts, and thus the first time ever that …

Comment: … the advertising and commercial aspects would have been relevant. (I'm ignoring commercial sub-orbital "hops" like the ones done in SpaceShip One.)